# Python immutable type ids and the is statment

Tags: python, string, tuples, immutable.js

I thought everything below would evaluate to False. Can someone explain what is going on? Don't immutable constructors create new objects (and new ids)?  How can the tuple have the same id and be different objects?

```
print((1,) is (1,))
print(id(1,) == id(1,))
print('a' is 'a')
print(id('a') == id('a'))
```

Result:

```
False
True
True
True
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second line is incorrect. You are passing `1` to `id`. (Python allows trailing commas in argument lists.)

```
print((1,) is (1,))
print(id((1,)) == id((1,)))
print('a' is 'a')
print(id('a') == id('a'))
```

Which are

```
False
False
True
True
```

So the results from `id` and `is` match.

---

It should be noted that the results of `is`/`id` can vary by implementation.

For example, in CPython 2.7, `2 * 2 is 4` but `2 * 200 is not 400`. For low integer vales, CPython uses the same memory addresses (which are the results of `id` in CPython). Again, this varies by implementation.

Comment: I've been using Python forever, and I never knew that it allowed a trailing (not trialing!) comma in a parameter list. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

You construct a new instance of the immutable type with every instance of a tuple.  The values of the tuple cannot change, but they are different (although equal) instances.

Answer (score 0):

It is probable that you can see the results of [interning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) with immutable objects in Python, Java, and others.

[PEP237](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0237/) states:

- Short ints with small values (typically between -1 and 99
    inclusive) are "interned" -- whenever a result has such a value,
    an existing short int with the same value is returned.  This is
    not done for long ints with the same values.  This difference
    will remain.  (Since there is no guarantee of this interning, is
    is debatable whether this is a semantic difference -- but code
    may exist that uses 'is' for comparisons of short ints and
    happens to work because of this interning.  Such code may fail
    if used with long ints.)

Examples:

```
>>> x=7
>>> y=10-3
>>> z=int('7')
>>> all(7 is e for e in [x,y,z])
True
>>> map(id, [x,y,z])
[140410571769784, 140410571769784, 140410571769784]
```

Strings:

```
>>> s1='abc'
>>> s2='abc'
>>> s1 is s2
True
>>> id(s1)
4378429560
>>> id(s2)
4378429560
```

You cannot rely on an instance of an immutable object being the only label of that object. It is an implementation detail that can vary across versions and implementations.

Answer (score 0):

```
print((1,) is (1,))
print(id(1,) == id(1,))
print('a' is 'a')
print(id('a') == id('a'))
```

1- first evaluates to false because the 2 tuples are different objects

2- it evaluates to true because `id(1,)` doesn't recognise `1,` as a tuple but just as a 1, and when you have small integers or strings python does an optimisation where it references 2 names to the same id so it doesn't have to allocate 2 different spaces. It'd be false if you had `id((1,))` since then it'd recognise it as a tuple

3 and 4 - they're true for the same reason as 2 is true